# CSV misalignment when reading in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV with a lot of headers. It ranges from Column A to AZ. I need to read only the first column of the CSV.

My issue is the last column (comments) bleeds into the first column when opened in notepad++ and it appears to show that it is apart of Column one (host name). When I run my code it reads it as notepad++ does.

I originally convert this from an .xls to a CSV file, is there a way to ensure the last column does not wrap around?

```
#region - Convert to CVS 
$strFileName = "C:\working\Server Count & Status Check ARC 0219183.xlsx"
$strSheetName = 'SCI$'
$strProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
$strDataSource = "Data Source = $strFileName"
$strExtend = "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"
$strQuery = "Select * from [$strSheetName]"

$objConn = New-Object 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("$strProvider;$strDataSource;$strExtend")
$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($strQuery)
$sqlCommand.Connection = $objConn
 $objConn.open()

$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($sqlCommand)
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
$da.fill($dt)



$dt | Export-Csv "C:\working\Server Count & Status Check ARC 0219183.csv" - 
NoTypeInformation

$objConn.close()
#endregion
```

[Original Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enxfW.png)

[After trying to gather first column(hostname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAj4F.png)

```
 $array=@{}

$ServerStatus = Get-Content "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\Linux Server 
Compare\Server Count & Status Check ARC 0219183.csv" | select -skip 1 |  
ConvertFrom-Csv  -Header "HostName","Business Application","Technical 
Function","Location","Environment","Day Number","Slot 
Number","SlotTime","Description","DNS Name","Key Server","Host Name","Public 
IP","Server Type","Build Date","Builder","Product Name","Serial 
No","Enclosure","Bay","CPU Model","CPU Socket","CPU Cores","Logical 
CPU","Memory","Up Time","Kernel Version","OS Type","Version","Patch 
level","Multipath Disks?","Multipath Checker?","Customized Fsck?","Splx 
Installed?","Splx Running?","Suse Manager Status","RHN Running ?","RHN 
Autostart?","Installed Kernel","Available Kernel in 
/boot","Hardened","Syslog 
Config correct ?","Syslog Running ?","Patrol Running?","Splunk 
Installed?","Splunk Running?","Puppet Installed?","Puppet 
Running?","Centrify 
Version","VM Tools Installed?","VM Tools Running?","Comments"

$ServerStatusObj = new-object Object
$ServerStatusObj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty  "Name" -value ""  
$ServerStatusObj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty  "Origin" -value ""  

$array=@{name = $ServerStatus.HostName}


  foreach ($name in $array.name){

         if($name -ne $null){

          $Value = $name


            if($name -ne $null){

            $ServerStatusObj.name =$Value
            $ServerStatusObj.Origin = " Linux Servers"
                                      } #End of IF
                        else {Write-Output "null"}

           Write-Output $ServerStatusObj | export-csv 
"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Scripts\Linux Server Compare\ServerStatusParse.csv"  -notypeinformation -Append        
                            }
```

Comment: It's very hard to say without seeing the source data. Maybe there's a soft line break (shift+enter) in the cell?

Comment: Plus, according to your code you are reading from an Excel file and writing to a CSV. Not reading from a CSV.

Comment: This is converting from an excel to a CSV without the use of excel. My servers do not have excel to use the excel object functionality.

Comment: My point is that you are reading from an Excel file. So whatever is going on in that excel file is most likely going to be the issue. Regardless you are going to have to give us more information. What does the input file look like? What are you seeing in the output file that makes you say the last column is bleeding into the first column? What does that even mean?

Comment: In a field with a name like "Comments" it most likely a carriage return _in_ the data field, as already stated. Is the data surrounded by quotes? If so, the wraparound should not be a problem for whatever is importing it. What are you using to import it?

Comment: The OP is using a SQL query to import it. It is right there in the code.

Comment: The next thing that I notice is that the connection string you are using is telling Excel that the file is a pre Excel 2007 file, but the name of the file indicates that it is 2007 or later.

Comment: I added more info. I tried to condense it since its large. Basically the name column in the second image should only contain the server names but it appears a piece of the comment field from the first image

Comment: I would start by using a proper connection string I suspect that it should be ***$strExtend = "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"***

Comment: The formatting appeared to be more clean in notepad however the issue remains

Comment: You can probably inspect the code that Doug Finke did for Import Excel. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/4.0.10

Comment: basically we probably won't be able to tell you flat out what the problem is without being able to reproduce it. If you can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that would help.

Comment: It appears  vonPryz was correct. In the comments field they have some spaces (alt +enters) in between them IN the comment column.  Every alt+enter between characters parses the info into a new line. I attached the second part of my code that takes only the host name.  Is there a way to just bypass that comments column all together?

Comment: $strQuery = "Select * from [$strSheetName]"  - Don't select *

Comment: Ahhhhh  $strQuery = "Select HostName from [$strSheetName]" Seems to grab what I need :)   thank you

Comment: @EBGreen There is no code anywhere importing this into SQL Server

Comment: No, but there is all the code using the MS OLEDB driver to load the DB engine and use a query for to load the data into memory.

Comment: Yes. The `Microsoft.ACE` OLE DB provider which is most definitely not SQL Server.

Comment: @EBGreen So I have another file however the host name column is now Separated by a space in the file and "Select HostName...." does not work in my powershell script . Any suggestions?

Comment: Put quotes around 'Host Name'

Comment: It does not work :(   Get this -                                                   "Expr1000"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"
"Host Name"

Comment: You should probably open a new question then fully explaining the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761538/converting-to-xlsx-to-csv-via-powershell-select-statement